# Natural Number Inductive Proof

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

Prove the following statement:

For every $\lambda$>1, there exists a number a∈N and b∈[0,1) such that $\lambda$=a+b.

I first defined a = sup{n ∈ N | n ≤ x}, so m is the integer part of x or the floor of ⌊x⌋. How would i rigorously prove the floor of x is the sup? Then I need to prove x-⌊x⌋=x-a<1, is this trivial or do I need to prove it too?

Comment: First, you mean "a is the integer part of x".  Also you don't mean "floor of ⌊x⌋".  ⌊x⌋ **is** the floor.  And you don't need to say "sup".  Since N is discrete "max" would be more precise.  Taking a to be max{n ∈ N | n ≤ x}, a+ 1> N so that 1> N- a= b.

Comment: I'd use the Archimedean property of $\Bbb R$ to show that $\{\,n\in\Bbb N\mid \lambda< n\,\}$ is non-empty. Then by well-order of $\Bbb N$, it has a minimal element $m$. From $\lambda>1$, conclude $m>1$, hence $a:=m-1\in\Bbb N$. Now $a\le \lambda<m=a+1$. Conclude that $b:=\lambda -a\in[0,1)$.

Comment: i know the archimedean property but how do i use it?

Comment: how would i know  a+ 1> N btw?

Answer (score 0):

In your other question you asked how to show
a real r >= 1 is in [n,n+1) for some n in N.
Use that result to conclude n is the integer part of r
and r - n the fractional part.

Comment: got it how about the statement [n,n+1)∩[m,m+1)$\neq$∅ only if n=m?

Comment: @jamesblack.  I have already  answered that.